# The right MSIX for publication in the Microsoft Store?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winui-3, winui

Am I using the correct msix for publishing to the Microsoft Store?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can publish a single x86 application package like the one you have in your picture.

To target multiple architectures, you could upload an app bundle. Please refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) page for more information about how to package an app and the different types of app packages that are available.